# Существует ли _общепринятое_ название игры

Tags: выбор-слов

Игра такая:
Дается прямоугольная таблица, заполненная буквами.
Часть букв по вертикали или по горизонтали составляет слова.
Задача игрока -- найти эти слова.

Существует ли у этой игры *общепринятое* название?

Добавила картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нашла, что Википедия называет это ["Головоломка по поиску слов"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)
Я правильно понимаю, что народ с этим названием не знаком?

Comment: Может, это филворд?

Comment: А в филворде все буквы принадлежат каким-либо словам? И могут ли слова пересекаться?

Comment: Это похоже на венгерский кроссворд (филворд).

Answer (score 1):

На английском эта игра обычно называется Word Search. Насколько я знаю, какого-то четкого устоявшегося названия на русском у нее нет. А "головоломка по поиску слов", конечно, может быть очень разной и плохо отражает суть предмета. Я бы использовал английское название, если бы мне нужно описать игру, но из вашего вопроса не вполне очевидно, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: Да, и название Word Search очень общепринятое. Или вы уже специалист и в американских игровых реалиях? Тогда бы вы не писали "Так что это какая-то очень детская игра...". Пожалуйста, не вводите посетителей комьюнити в заблуждение. Это всюду называется ИМЕННО Word search или Word search puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Это, вообще-то, английский кроссворд. Он отличается от венгерского кроссворда (филворда) тем, что слова в английском  кроссворде могут пересекаться и расположены строго по прямой, чего не скажешь за его собрата.

Comment: Если так, то как он называется по-английски? Crossword - это обычный кроссворд

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4 Вот Вики. Надо сказать, весьма субъективное мнение. Но главное то, что основным в том определении является отсутствие "лишних" букв (или они составляют "ключевое" слово). Здесь же мы имеем посность заполненный квадрать в котором только некоторые буквы принадлежат словам. Так что весьма условно можно назвать "английским" даже руководствуясь определением из Вики.

Answer (score 0):

[Филворд](http://pomozgui.ru/stati/?filvord__raznovidnost_krossvorda)

Венгерский кроссворд (другое название филворд) имеет поле без черных клеток и нумерации. Все поле заполнено буквами. Каждая буква может входить в состав только одного слова. Слова в этом кроссворде не пересекаются и не образуют «крестов» – это одно из основных отличий филворда от классического кроссворда.

Comment: Похоже, но не оно. Я добавила картинку.

Answer (score 0):

Знаю этот тип головоломок, но это не филфорд, конечно. 
В филфордах слова составляются не обязательно по прямой и нельзя одну и ту же букву использовать дважды. 
Так что это какая-то очень детская игра...

Короче, выяснилось, что названия отдельного нету. С очень большими оговорками можно найти назвать "английским кроссвордом" - в понимании википедии.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4

Хотя тут не выполнено ключевое условие определения Википедии - отсутствие ненужных букв. Не просто "лишних", из которых потом составляется ключевое слово, а именно лишних, которые потом вообще никак не используются.

Следеет еще сказать, что на английском я такого названия не нашел. Так что это из серии американских горок, которые "американские" - только в России, а в Америке - русские.

Comment: То есть если вы прочитаете название  "Головоломка по поиску слов", то догадаетесь, что речь идет именно об этой игре? Или у нее есть еще названия?

Comment: Я этого не говорил. Не догадаюсь. Но здесь нету "или". Может быть и есть какое-то название. Но не шибко известное и уж конечно не общепринятое. Вот на английском Word Search более говорящее.

Comment: Это сообщение не является ответом так как не предлагает никакого варианта ответа на заданный вопрос. Думаю, что оно должно было быть комментарием к вопросу или одному из ответов.

Comment: Nick Volynkin, вы глубоко ошибаетесь. Вопрос был "есть ли название на русском" - и мой ответ был "Нет, не существует". Другое дело, что я, когда писал, не был на 100% уверен в нем. Поэтому сформулировал с доле вероятности.

Answer (score 0):

## Хаос слов

Довольно красочное название, упоминается в [том числе в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Поскольку никакой вариант ещё не получил большой популярности в русском языке, можно просто поддерживать тот, который вам нравится.

Вот, например, сайт, зарегистрированный под этим названием: http://russian.wordchaos.com/

Comment: А ссылочку хотя бы на Вики можно?